# Artifact name which triggered Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

Jenkins will start job(freestyle) by Artifactory trigger.
How do I get name of that file which triggered the job. So that I can use file name later in same job(no need to download file)?

Answer (score 1):

You can figure it out by executing a simple REST API:

```
GET https://<base-url>/artifactory/api/storage/<path>?lastModified
```

Response:

```
{
  "uri": <full path of last modified artifact in Artifactory>,
  "lastModified": "<last modification time>"
}
```

However, using this method is is not 100% accurate because the last modified artifact may be different than the artifact which triggered the build.

For more information, see the the Artifactory REST API documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemLastModified

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
Jenkins Artifactory plugin 3.9.0 is released. On this version, the URL of the build cause is exposed to be accessed by pipelines - an extra REST request is not needed.

You can find here the relevant documentation for [scripted](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-BuildTriggers) and [declarative](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-BuildTriggers) pipelines.

You can find here examples for [scripted](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/build-trigger-example/Jenkinsfile#L4) and [declarative](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/build-trigger-example/Jenkinsfile#L7) pipelines.